# postscript rectangle dimensions

Tags: rectangles, postscript

Drawing rectangles from postscript, it seems that the dimensions I give are taken as the middle points of the four lines; I would however like to get a rectangle with my given parameters as the outside dimensions.
For example:

```
newpath 4 setlinewidth 0 0 20 20 rectstroke
```

seems to produce a square with sides of 24 points, rather than the 20 that I wanted.
Is my impression correct? If so, what to do about it? Of course I can declare a my_rectstroke( function, that will take the linewidth as a parameter plus the coordinates and dimensions, but perhaps there is a more elegant/less cumbersome way?

Comment: Yes, you need to compensate for the linewidth. Thick lines are centered at the outline of the path.